# How to display coordinates and use ginput

Tags: matlab, user-interface, mousemove, matlab-figure, cursor-position

I cannot seem to get my image to display the coordinates of my mouse cursor, and also use ginput to store points at the same time.

I currently am trying the following:

```
MriHotrod = imread('Image.bmp');
Fig = figure('Name','BobDole'),...
    imshow(Image, 'InitialMagnification', 250)

axis on
impixelinfo

Image_1 = ginput(4)

close BobDole
```

The ginput still works, but the impixelinfo stays constant

```
Pixel Info = (X, Y) Pixel Value
```

I am aware of some methods of getting around this, but they involve functions. This seems like a rather simple problem that can avoid the use of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you type `edit ginput` and scroll to line 238-ish, you'll see

```
% Adding this to enable automatic updating of currentpoint on the figure 
set(fig,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@(o,e) dummy());
```

In other words, `ginput` sets a `WindowButtonMotionFcn` in the figure. My guess is that `impixelinfo` uses this function as well, so it gets disabled as soon as `ginput` is called.

Indeed, in `impixelinfoval` (a function used by `impixelinfo`) we find around line 83:

```
callbackID = iptaddcallback(hFig,'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @displayPixelInfo);
```

The odd thing is then: how does it get reset after you click 4 points?

This magic is accomplished by line 222-ish of `ginput`:

```
initialState.uisuspendState = uisuspend(fig);
```

Apparently, `uisuspend` is a little undocumented function that is used to suspend any pre-existing `WindowButton*` functions, in order to reset them later. So, if you comment out this line

```
%initialState.uisuspendState = uisuspend(fig);
```

and save `ginput`, and re-do the whole thing, you see the behavior you want.

You will also see why these functions get suspended in the first place -- For reasons I do not quite understand, everything gets unworkably slow when two such functions are enabled.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, unfortunately our ginput functions must be very different, as none of the lines you mentioned are in my ginput function. I tried commenting this out:                                       state = uisuspend(fig)                                                    This appears at line 92. This did not work however.

Comment: What version of Matlab do you have?

Comment: Ah. I have R2012a. Apparently they changed it a lot in the past 2 years. Anyway, the reasoning should still hold. Do you always re-execute *all* commands after saving?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but I save the edits, and then rerun my script. But no worries, thanks so much for the help I will go through the ginput with a fine tooth comb, or just get the R2012a ginput function from a friend. Thanks again!

Comment: With R2010a comment these 2 lines: Lines 92 & 183.